# C# Sqlite no update

Tags: c#, sqlite

**Dashboard1 class**     this code checks for all rated work and adds up the sum total of rate and is used in the update query to update the user who did the work

```
        {
            // rate
            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                if (comboBox1.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Warning : Select Rate value");
                }
                else
                {                   
                    Author au = new Author();
                    au.rateReview(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text));
                    List<int> score = new List<int>();
                    string sql = "select work.rate from work WHERE work.id ="+ listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text+";";
                    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source =DatabaseFile.db3");
                    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {     
                        score.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["rate"].ToString()));
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    res = score.AsQueryable().Sum();
                   // MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
                    au_update_assigned();
                   string sql1 = "Update user Set score = "+res+" where id =" + userid + ";";
                    Database db = new Database();

                    db.insert(sql1);

                    MessageBox.Show(sql1);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error : Select Work from List");
            }

        }
```

**Database class**

Insert function is called from the database class

````
 public void insert(string query)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } ```

The button even is from a **dashboard1 class** when the insert function is from the **database class** I am using sqlite  I have checked for syntax error exception error  but I just won't seem to up to update. It first queries for all user rated work then creates a sum total which is supposed to be part of the update command  all fields have been filled
````

Comment: you need a valid connection, try pass connection to insert function

Comment: this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a connection opened and a commad to execute SQL instruction, try change:

```
Database db = new Database();
db.insert(sql1);
MessageBox.Show(sql1);
```

to:

```
conn.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd2 = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
cmd2.CommandText="Update user Set score = "+res+" where id =" + userid + ";";
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery ( );
conn.Close();
```

or pass connection to insert function:

```
 public void insert(string query, SQLiteConnection _conn )
    {
        _conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(_conn);
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _conn.Close();
    }
```

and call:

```
db.insert(sql1, cnn);
```